# Split a dataframe into n dataframes by column value in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a large Polars dataframe that I'd like to split into n number of dataframes given the size. Like take dataframe and split it into 2 or 3 or 5 dataframes.

There are several observations that will show up for each column and would like to choose splitting into a chosen number of dataframes. A simple example is like the following where I am splitting on a specific id, but would like to have similar behave, but more like split into 2 approximately even dataframes since the full example has a large number of identifiers.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'Identifier': [1234,1234, 2345,2345],
                   'DateColumn': ['2022-02-13','2022-02-14', '2022-02-13',
                                  '2022-02-14']
                   })
df2 = df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col('DateColumn').str.strptime(pl.Date).cast(pl.Date)
    ]
)

print(df)
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ Identifier ┆ DateColumn │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ i64        ┆ str        │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1234       ┆ 2022-02-13 │
│ 1234       ┆ 2022-02-14 │
│ 2345       ┆ 2022-02-13 │
│ 2345       ┆ 2022-02-14 │
└────────────┴────────────┘


df1 = df.filter(
    pl.col('Identifier')==1234
)

df2 = df.filter(
    pl.col('Identifier')==2345
)

print(df1)
```

shape: (2, 2)

```
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ Identifier ┆ DateColumn │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ i64        ┆ str        │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1234       ┆ 2022-02-13 │
│ 1234       ┆ 2022-02-14 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
print(df2)

┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ Identifier ┆ DateColumn │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ i64        ┆ str        │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2345       ┆ 2022-02-13 │
│ 2345       ┆ 2022-02-14 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Would this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786434/20557510

Answer (score 5):

If you want to divide your DataFrame by let's say your identifier, the best way to do so is use the partition_by method.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
    "N": [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
    "bar": ["k", "l", "m", "m", "l"],
})

df.partition_by(groups="foo", maintain_order=True)
[shape: (2, 3)
 ┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
 │ foo ┆ N   ┆ bar │
 │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
 │ str ┆ i64 ┆ str │
 ╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
 │ A   ┆ 1   ┆ k   │
 │ A   ┆ 2   ┆ l   │
 └─────┴─────┴─────┘,
 shape: (2, 3)
 ┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
 │ foo ┆ N   ┆ bar │
 │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
 │ str ┆ i64 ┆ str │
 ╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
 │ B   ┆ 2   ┆ m   │
 │ B   ┆ 4   ┆ m   │
 └─────┴─────┴─────┘,
 shape: (1, 3)
 ┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
 │ foo ┆ N   ┆ bar │
 │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
 │ str ┆ i64 ┆ str │
 ╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
 │ C   ┆ 2   ┆ l   │
 └─────┴─────┴─────┘]
```

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html

This automatically divides the DataFrame by values in a column.